# Moving Files with Certain Extension to Calculated Subdirectory

Tags: applescript

Apologies if this is a horrible question but I tried searching and came up with some results that did not work for me. I am new to the world of Applescript but trying to get proficient to make a few things at work easier.

I am trying to write a code that will

1) Find all files of a certain extension within the selected folder in Finder

2) Determine the destination folder based off of the source folder and a preset subdirectory structure

3) move files with extension X to the appropriate folder

Logically it seems rather simple but my lack of understanding is making this very difficult for me. Find below my code. It works up to the second tell, and displays the proper test path dialog. However I get the error -

"Can’t get every file of..." for the sourceFolder.

Any thoughts?

```
tell application "Finder"

set sourceFolder to POSIX path of ((target of front Finder window) as text)

end tell

set subPath to "TestPath/TestPath/"

set destFolder to sourceFolder & subPath

-- folders to sort into
set rawPath to destFolder & "RAW/"
set xmpPath to destFolder & "RAW/"
set tiffPath to destFolder & "TIFF/"

--extension list
set rawExt to {".nef", ".NEF", ".dng"}
set xmpExt to {".xmp"}
set tiffExt to {".tif"}

set testName to tiffPath & "TestFileName" & tiffExt

display dialog testName


tell application "Finder"

    repeat with eachFile in every file in sourceFolder
        if name extension of eachFile is in rawExt then
            move file eachFile to rawPath
        else if name extension of eachFile is in xmpExt then
            move file eachFile to xmpPath
        else if name extension of eachFile is in tiffExt then
            move file eachFile to tiffPath
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: The Finder does not support POSIX paths. You have to use Finder file specifiers (keyword `file` plus a colon separated HFS path) or AppleScript alias specifiers.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. The script now runs all the way through without throwing an error message, but no files are moved. Something then within the second Finder tell must be awry?

Comment: I wrote an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of your script using HFS paths.

There is another main issue: The extension in the lists must be declared without a leading dot.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set sourceFolder to ((target of front Finder window) as text)
end tell

set subPath to "TestPath:TestPath:"

set destFolder to sourceFolder & subPath

-- folders to sort into
set rawPath to destFolder & "RAW:"
set xmpPath to destFolder & "RAW:"
set tiffPath to destFolder & "TIFF:"

--extension list
set rawExt to {"nef", "NEF", "dng"}
set xmpExt to {"xmp"}
set tiffExt to {"tif"}

set testName to tiffPath & "TestFileName" & tiffExt

display dialog testName


tell application "Finder"

    repeat with eachFile in (get every file in folder sourceFolder)
        if name extension of eachFile is in rawExt then
            move eachFile to folder rawPath
        else if name extension of eachFile is in xmpExt then
            move eachFile to folder xmpPath
        else if name extension of eachFile is in tiffExt then
            move eachFile to folder tiffPath
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks again Vadian. Using the code above I am now up to the error "Can't make alias....into type integer" on the line move eachFile to folder rawPath. Is this due to the way I am using the move commands?

Comment: I tested the code successfully. Even if the target folder is empty this error must not occur.